# Saving data in table using localStorage

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I have an HTML table along with a button which adds a row every time it is clicked. There is also a button that saves all the data in the table into `localStorage`. The problem I am having occurs every every time I add a row. It currently fails to save the new row.

Also, if someone knows how to save an image in `localStorage`, that would be helpful as well.

Here is my JavaScript code:

```js
function addRow() {
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    var row = table.insertRow();
    var cell1 = row.insertCell();
    var cell2 = row.insertCell();
    var cell3 = row.insertCell();
    var cell4 = row.insertCell();
    var cell5 = row.insertCell();
  
    var input = document.createElement("input");
    input.type = "file";
    input.accept = "image/*";
    input.onchange = uploadFile;
    cell1.appendChild(input);
    cell2.innerHTML = '<input type="text" placeholder="שם מוצר">';
    cell3.innerHTML = '<input type="text" placeholder="מחיר מוצר" pattern="[0-9]*">';
    cell4.innerHTML = '<input type="text" placeholder="תיאור מוצר">';
    cell5.innerHTML = '<button type="button" onclick="deleteRow(this)">מחק</button>';
  
    saveData();


function deleteRow(button) {
    var row = button.parentNode.parentNode;
    row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
}

function saveData() {
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    var products = [];
    for (var i = 1, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
      var product = {
        image: row.cells[0].getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src,
        name: row.cells[1].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value,
        price: row.cells[2].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value,
        description: row.cells[3].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value
      };
      products.push(product);
    }
    localStorage.setItem('products', JSON.stringify(products));
  }



function uploadFile(event) {
    var file = event.target.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
        var image = document.createElement("img");
        image.src = e.target.result;
        image.style.maxWidth = "120px";
        image.style.maxHeight = "120px";
        var cell = event.target.parentNode.parentNode;
        cell.innerHTML = "";
        cell.appendChild(image);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}

function loadData() {
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    var data = localStorage.getItem("products");

    // ניקוי הטבלה מכל השורות הקיימות לפני טעינת הנתונים
    while (table.rows.length > 1) {
        table.deleteRow(1);
    }

    if (data) {
        data = JSON.parse(data);
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var row = table.insertRow();
            var cell1 = row.insertCell();
            var cell2 = row.insertCell();
            var cell3 = row.insertCell();
            var cell4 = row.insertCell();
            var cell5 = row.insertCell();

            cell1.innerHTML = '<img src="' + data[i].image + '" alt="Product Image" style="max-width: 120px; max-height: 120px;">';
            cell2.innerHTML = '<input type="text" placeholder="שם מוצר" value="' + data[i].name + '">';
            cell3.innerHTML = '<input type="text" placeholder="מחיר מוצר" pattern="[0-9]*" value="' + data[i].price + '">';
            cell4.innerHTML = '<input type="text" placeholder="תיאור מוצר" value="' + data[i].description + '">';
            cell5.innerHTML = '<button type="button" onclick="deleteRow(this)">מחק</button>';
        }
    }
}

loadData();
```

I tried to swap the order of the functions, and it didn't help. I built most of the code using ChatGPT, but it could not fix this part for me. I have tried both Google Bard and Edge AI.

Comment: You can't save an image in local storage per se .. But you **can** convert the image to a base64 string and save that into storage :)

Comment: Please make sure to translate your title too

Comment: The addRow function has no closing `}`.  Is that a typo in the question or is it like that in your code as well?

Answer (score 0):

You can read an image as Base64 data and save that data as a string in local storage.  Here's a quick example of how to read the image and convert it to a string and display an image based on that string.  You just need to save and retrive the data from localstorage instead of doing it directly like I am here

```js
function readImage(url, callback) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onload = function() {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function() {
      callback(reader.result);
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(xhr.response);
  };
  xhr.open('GET', url);
  xhr.responseType = 'blob';
  xhr.send();
}

readImage(document.querySelector('#original').src, (data) => {
  //Save `data` to localStorage since it's now just a Base64 string
  
  //You can just set `data` to the image src like this;
  document.querySelector('#base64Img').src = data;
});
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/100/200/200" id="original">

<h4>Image created from Base64 string below</h4>
<img id="base64Img">
```